# What is a better way to state this?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T : V → W$ be a linear map of finite dimensional vector spaces. Prove that $T$ is surjective (respectively, injective) if and only if $T^*$ is injective (respectively, surjective).

What is a better way to state this?

Comment: Um, the statement looks fine, are you wondering how to prove it? I don't really understand your issue with this.

Comment: (respectively, injective) just means show both sur. and inj.?

Comment: A statement of the form "if X (resp. X'), then Y (resp. Y')" should be read as two implications: (1) X implies Y and (2) X' implies Y'.

Comment: That's what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The statement seems fine as it is. However, if you do not know about the convention used, I will describe how it is read. There are really two statements contained in the expression "$T$ is surjective (respectively, injective) if and only if $T^{\ast}$ is injective (respectively, surjective)."

The first statement ignores the parentheses: "$T$ is surjective if and only if $T^{\ast}$ is injective." The second statement replaces what comes before the parentheses with what is in the parentheses: "$T$ is injective if and only if $T^{\ast}$ is surjective."

In general, when ever you see a statement of the form "if $X$ (respectively, $X'$), then $Y$ (respectively, $Y'$)" then you read it as the statements "if $X$ then $Y$" and "if $X'$ then $Y'$".